# Creating a Slice of Concrete Types and Casting to its Respective Interface

Tags: go

Having some issues creating a slice of interfaces and initiating it to its concrete type, any help would be greatly appretiated

Interface

```
type MatrixElement interface {
    GetValue() Element
    GetCoordinate() Coordinate
}
```

Concrete Implementation

```
type LocatableElement struct {
    value datastructures.Element
    coordinate datastructures.Coordinate
}

func (ele LocatableElement)GetValue() datastructures.Element {
    return ele.value
}

func (ele LocatableElement)GetCoordinate() datastructures.Coordinate {
    return ele.coordinate
}

func CreateLocatableElement(value datastructures.Element, coordinate datastructures.Coordinate) LocatableElement {
    return LocatableElement{
        value: value,
        coordinate: coordinate,
    }
}
```

Defining the Type as a slice

```
type HorizontalMatrix [][]datastructures.MatrixElement
```

Creating an instance of the new HorizonatlMatrix

```
func CreateHorizontalMatrix(rows int, columns int) HorizontalMatrix {
    horzMatrix := make([][]matrix.LocatableElement, rows)
    for i := 0; i < rows; i++ {
        horzMatrix[i] = make([]matrix.LocatableElement, columns)
    }
    return horzMatrix;
}
```

`cannot use horzMatrix (type [][]matrix.LocatableElement) as type HorizontalMatrix in return argument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't neither cast `[]ConcreteTypes([]Interfaces)` nor assert `[]Interfaces.([]ConcreteTypes)` nevertheless  `ConcreteTypes` implements `Interfaces`. You should either define container

```
type Matrix interface{
    GetElem(abs, ord int) MatrixElement 
}
```

and satisfy it for `HorizontalMatrix` or make matrix as []interface

```
horzMatrix := make([][]matrix.MatrixElement, rows)
horzMatrix[i] = make([]matrix.MatrixElement, columns)
```

and than populate it with concrete type `LocatableElement`

Comment: So technically if I'm understanding correctly `horzMatrix` is just allocating references to the interface (only pointer allocation) no actual allocation to the physical data structure which is actually going to hold the physical payload is done


Only when assignment `horzMatrix[row][column]` is the allocation to the actual `LocatableElement` done. (where the LocatableElement structure is allocated and created and the pointer created previously is made to point to the newly allocated structure)

Comment: @MrX, [more background](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface) on your issue.